# Equiintegrability of some family of sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(\rho_n)_n\subset L^1$ be a Dirac sequence. Study the equiintegrability of the following family:

(a) $f_n=\rho_n^2$,

(b) $g_n=\rho_1*\rho_n$ (convolution),

(c) $g_n=\rho_1*\rho_n^2$.

**My attempt**

Since for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $\int_{|x|<\epsilon}|\rho_n(x)|dx\rightarrow 1$, $(\rho_n)_n$ is not equiintegrable.

(b) Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta$ such that $m(A)\leq \delta$ implies $\int_A|\rho_1(x)|dx<\epsilon$. Then
    \begin{align*} \int_A|g_n(x)|dx&=\int_A|\rho_1*\rho_n|dx\\
&=\int_A\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\rho_1(x-y)| |\rho_n(y)|dydx\\
   &=\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\rho_n(y)|\left(\int_A|\rho_1(x-y)|dx\right)dy\\
   &\leq \epsilon \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\rho_n(y)|dy=\epsilon.
 \end{align*}
     Hence, the family $(g_n)_n$ is equiintegrable.

(a) I suspect its not equintegrable but I do not know what procee. 
\begin{align*} \int_A|f_n(x)|dx&=\int_A|\rho_n^2|dx.
 \end{align*}
I hope to get this kind of inequality
\begin{align*} \int_A|\rho_n^2|dx&\leq\int_A|\rho_n|dx \int_A|\rho_n|dx.
 \end{align*}

Comment: What is a Dirac sequence and are you sure it is in $\mathbf{R}$? It sounds like the $\rho_n$ are measures.

Comment: A Dirac sequence is one that satisfies $\rho_n\geq 0$, $\int_R\rho=1$ and $\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\rho_n\rightarrow 0$. I mean in that that the domain is $R$